# Problema con cierre de etiquetas confuso

Tags: html, css

muy buenas noches.
Estoy realizando un archivo HTML para poder inyectarlo en un mensaje Email.
Cómo he leído, he estado ocupando tablas, después de saber que los div no iban bien con correos, debido a esto, he cambiado todos los contenedores a `<tr>/<td>`.
Pero en uno de ellos, me salta un error

> "Element a is not closed"

Por lo tanto, no puedo continuar con el insertado de imagen para mi diseño.

He hecho un tipo de debug y no he encontrado el lugar, he cerrado en todas partes, y aún así esta etiqueta me falla, no sé que hacer.

```
<table style="max-width: 600px; padding: 10px; margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td id="background-banner" style="position: relative; box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px white inset; background-image: url('#')">
            <a href="#">
                <img id="banner-image" src="#" style="
                margin-left: 15px;
                border-radius: 80px;
                max-height: 400px;
                max-width: 450px;
                box-shadow: -2px 1px 5px #8b0000;
                border: 5px solid #6F4E37;">

                <h1 id="title-banner" style="
                @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Redressed&display=swap');
                @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mukta:wght@200&display=swap');
                @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&family=Shizuru&display=swap');
                top: 25px;
                font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
                font-size: 28px;
                margin-left: 35px;
                color: #006400;"> SAMPLE TEXT</h1>
                ***<td class="icons-overlay">
                    <img id="meme-one" src="#" alt="" style="
                        width: 150px;
                        position: absolute;
                        margin-left: 90px;
                        top: 125px;">
                </td>***

            </a>
```

En el lugar recalcado me da este error... no entiendo que está fallando.

PD: `<tables>` y etiquetas han sido cerradas abajo en código que no he puesto aquí.

Comment: la etiqueta img no tiene cierre

Comment: Estoy intentando cerrar, pero me aparece en plomo, creo que no necesito cerrar con </img>

Comment: O no sé si hablas de cerrar el tag en si... porque están cerrados :(

Comment: Muestra el código completo del Table para ver si está faltando cerrar algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código que pasaste falta el cierre del tr, el primer td y el cierre de table.
El img tampoco está cerrado, es del tipo self-closing, por lo que no lleva una etiqueta de cierre, sino que debes agregar después de sus estilos inline un **/>**.

**Ejemplo de etiqueta img:**

```
<img src="..." style="....." />
```

Revisa también si la etiqueta **a** está abriendo y cerrando realmente donde lo necesitas.

Respetar el órden de las etiquetas:

**Ej:**

```
<table> apertura tabla
  <a href=""> apertura anchor
    <tr> fila
      <td> apertura columna1
       ...
      <td> cierre columna1
      <td> apertura columna2
       ...
      <td> cierre columna2
    <tr> cierre fila
  <a/> cierre anchor
<table> cierre tabla
```

Si la etiqueta **a** abre antes de un **tr** esta debe cerrar después del mismo, si se abre antes de la apertura de un **tr** y se cierra antes del cierre de ese mismo **tr**, esto podría generar inconvenientes.